# Next.js multi step form with routing

Tags: reactjs, next.js

My Next.js multistep form works just fine, switching between steps all on one page index.js

```
return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Next.js Multi Step Form</title>
      </Head>
      < Navbar />
        <div className={styles.container}>
          <FormCard>
            {formStep >= 0 && (
              <ContractInfo
                formStep={formStep}
                prevFormStep={prevFormStep}
                nextFormStep={nextFormStep}
              />
            )}
            {formStep >= 1 && (
              <PersonalInfo
                formStep={formStep}
                prevFormStep={prevFormStep}
                formStepToLast={formStepToLast}
              />
            )}
            {formStep >= 2 && (
              <ConfirmPurchase
                formStep={formStep}
                prevFormStep={prevFormStep}
                nextFormStep={nextFormStep}
              />

            )}
          </FormCard>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
```

**UPDATE**

After trying out the below suggestions, I ended up having my path updated. I also simplifies my code (hardcoded), as I only have two steps. The current code for the index.js looks the following:

```
const App = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [formStep, setFormStep] = useState(0);
  const { setFormValues } = useContext(FormContext);

  useEffect(() => { router.push(`/?step=${formStep}`), setFormStep(formStep) }, [formStep]);
  
  const nextFormStep = (contract='') => {
    setFormStep(1);
    setFormValues({ contract });
  };


  const prevFormStep = () => {
    setFormStep((formStep) => formStep - 1);
    
  };

  const formStepToLast = () => {
    setFormStep(2);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Next.js Multi Step Form</title>
      </Head>
      < Navbar />
        <div className={styles.container}>
            {formStep >= 0 && (
              <ContractInfo
                formStep={formStep}
                prevFormStep={prevFormStep}
                nextFormStep={nextFormStep}
              />
            )}
            {formStep >= 1 && (
              <PersonalInfo
                formStep={formStep}
                prevFormStep={prevFormStep}
                formStepToLast={formStepToLast}
              />
            )}
            {formStep >= 2 && (
              <ConfirmPurchase
                formStep={formStep}
                prevFormStep={prevFormStep}
                nextFormStep={nextFormStep}
              />
            )}  
        </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Still, I am not managing to navigate through form with the browser Back / Next buttons. It will change the path, but won't render the corresponding component. I assume, it hast smth. to do with the State. If I set useState to (1), it will render the right corresponding component under http://localhost:3000/?step=1, so, it does save the state. However navigating with the browser Buttons is impossible.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a query parameter to set the `formStep` and `router.push` to handle the form steps within the same page but have different URLs displayed.

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function IndexPage() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const formStep = router.query.step ?? 0;

    // Remaining JSX code
}
```

Then, on the action to go to the first form step you can call something like the following.

```js
router.push('/?step=1', '/personal_info');
```

This will update the URL on the browser and re-render the page with the `formStep >= 1` components visible.

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-thunder-w71yc?file=/pages/index.js) with a simplified version of your logic.

Comment: This works amazing, until I try back and forth buttons in the browser. In your sandbox they work, I have an issue, that my formSteps are part of state. const [formStep, setFormStep] = useState(0); I guess this is why browser won't really gon back/forth

Comment: Set the initial state to `const [formStep, setFormStep] = useState(router.query.step ?? 0);`, that should handle it.

Comment: Browser Back Button leads me to localhost/3000, but still renders step 1, not step 0 as it shoud

Comment: Do you even need to have `formStep` as part of state if you're handling it through query params, though? You may want to refactor that logic a bit. Or if you really need the state, please provide the rest of your component's code.

Comment: @juliomalves The Code is a bit complicated, as states are partly handeled the the context, I guess this is why browser doesn't 'save' history. However formStep is needed for component rendering. I tried to post relevant code bits above.

Comment: You can use `useEffect` to check router changes and changes the state

Comment: I tried already `useEffect(() => {router.push(`/?step=${formStep}`);}, [formStep]);`. No success. It just doesn't know which component belongs to which URL. That is why browser history won't work.

Comment: I believe @NishargShah meant using `useEffect` to update the state, e.g., `useEffect(() => { setFormStep(router.query.step); }, [router.query.step]);`.

Comment: Unfortunatelly won't let me use router outside of UseEffect. Error: No router instance found. you should only use "next/router" inside the client side of your app. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-router-instance

Comment: I still didn't figure it out. I tried everything above. console.log(router.query.step) is 0 when I go back in the browser, url http://localhost:3000/?step=0, but the formStep rendered ist still one. If I use my back-button console.log(router.query.step) is 1  1 0, then it renders right and I get the right form step rendered (0)