# Shallow Routing NEXT.js with Browser Back/Forth buttons

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have managed to change the path on click of the Next button in my multi step form.

```
    <div className="mt-3 sm:mt-0 sm:ml-3">
       <a
         onClick={() => {
         formStepToLast();
         {router.push(`/?step=${+2}`, undefined, {
            shallow: true
          });
        }; 
       }
    }
    className="w-full flex items-center justify-center px-8 py-3 border border-transparent text-base font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-yellow-500 hover:bg-yallow-600 md:py-4 md:text-lg md:px-10"
                  >
       Next
     </a>
 </div>
```

So onClick the user proceeds to the next step of the form and the path changes to /step=2 or whatever step it is. I just reproduced one step here. BUT, the browser buttons won't navigate correctly. If I use those, I just stay on current step. So, basically step=1 won't get 'assigned' to the FormStep1 of the form, same is with FormStep2. Did I forget smth?

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68791087/next-js-multi-step-form-with-routing/68791341#68791341

Comment: This is browser button bug I am having... It seemed different to me.

Comment: I don't think so, both questions are different but the answers are the same, xDD